# Is there a way to pull list of org Ids or user ids that have installed my connected app

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps

Is there any way to get some metrics on connected app oauth usage across Salesforce orgs. Use case I am trying to solve is I need to get metrics around the usage of my connected app so that I know what all users have granted api permissions to their org through it and get all the org Ids where the connected app is installed as a result of that.
Not sure if any of this is even possible, was not able to find anything around this in the documentation.

ps:  I am not looking to get the oauth usage for the connected app just from the org where it is created but across Salesforce platform.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your use case?

Comment: @sfdcfox with a connected app and integration Salesforce asks for a report periodically in which they need how many users, what all org ids are using that connected app or are connecting to salesforce app through it. I guess they need these metrics so they can charge accordingly if it's a paid integration that is using the connected app. so was wondering if there is any easy way to get the metrics